# React suite date-range picker not working in prod

Tags: reactjs, rsuite

I successfully added the react-suite date-range picker to my code and I was able to test it out locally but when I moved to the staging environment, the picker/input appears but the calenders do not when you click on it. There are no errors on the console either.

```
import { DateRangePicker } from 'rsuite';
import "rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css";


class SampleComponent extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
           <DateRangePicker
              oneTap
              appearance="default"
              placeholder="Select Date"
              style={{ width: 300, marginTop:'1em' }}
              onChange={this.handleSelect}
            />
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I  may had the same problem just few days ago, it may the cause is conflict between the css library with bootstrap one because they have same classes name, check on the inspect after you click on the clandear, its may hidden because of the class named  .fade.in  you may need it to set like this { opacity: 1 !important; }, if it's not the same problem sorry just want to help